My Cell Fracture fragments freak out when I apply Rigid Body
I'm trying to follow a youtube blender tutorial for a head explosion that was made in blender 2.9 I believe (i'm working in 4.0). When I cell fracture the front part of my skull model all is fine, until i apply the Rigid Body physics to all the segments - the segments all rotate in multiple directions and then go invisible on certain frames before coming back again. Blend file included - any help would be much appreciated!
.blend https://we.tl/t-T9DPW6sVF8

Have you made sure that the origin point for each object is in the middle of your geometry? That can cause weird things to happen when using rigid body physics. You can try selecting all your fragments, right-clicking, clicking on Set Origin, and finally clicking on Origin to Geometry

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Select all the pieces, right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry, and CtrlA > (Apply) Rotation and Scale, select one of the pieces, give it a Rigid Body simulation, Collisions > Shape > Mesh, and Sensitivity > Margin > 0, select all the other ones, make sure that the one that has the simulation is the active one, and go into the Object menu (top bar) > Rigid Body > Copy from Active. If you are glad with the result, go into the Scene panel > Rigid Body World > Cache, choose the simulation End frame and click on Bake:


Thank you so much! I'll try this is as soon as I get back from work!

Aghhh! I'm still getting the same issue - I know if it's something to do with the original mesh's state in edit mode? I had issues trying to move and rotate the front portion of the skull and realised it might be because I accidentally did something to it in edit mode? Should I also be doing this on frame 0? Thanks for the help! I'm quite new to blender!

Please share the latest version of your file
